# Como acceder al valor de un objeto especifico en PHP pasando el valor el valor de otro atributo?

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce

estoy trabajando con la API de woocommerce, el json que obtengo es asi:

```
  [
   {
    id: 8303,
    name: "GAP - Camiseta de manga corta para hombre, cuello redondo, algodón, color liso",
    price: "800",
    regular_price: "1000",
    sale_price: "800",
    meta_data: [
    {
      id: 24702,
      key: "_wp_page_template",
      value: "default"
    },
    {
      id: 24703,
      key: "_wpuf_form_id",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      id: 24704,
      key: "_wpuf_lock_editing_post",
      value: "no"
    },
    {
      id: 24705,
      key: "slide_template",
      value: "default"
    },
    **{
      id: 24706,
      key: "_alg_wc_cog_cost",
      value: "13.80"
    },**
    
    ]        
   }
  ]
```

necesito actualizar los atributos "price","regular_price" y "sale_price", con esto no tengo problemas, pero tambien necesito el valor del atributo que esta dentro del array meta_data con la **key: "_alg_wc_cog_cost"** luego realizar otra operacion, es decir que espeificando esa "key" pueda obtener el valor dentro del atributo **value** que en este ejemplo es 13.80.

tengo algo como esto:

```
public function getProducts($page)
    {
        $cambio = [
            'price' => '800',
            'regular_price' => '1000',
            'sale_price' => '800'
        ];
        
        $this->woocommerce()->put('products/8303', $cambio);
        return response()->json('proceso completado');
    }
```

pero aun necesito obtener el valor dentro del array meta_data con la key: "_alg_wc_cog_cost".
GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que recorrer el array y buscar esa key. Te paso una función genérica que te buscaría cualquier object dado el key en ese array:

```
public function getMetadataByKey($metadata,$key) {
    foreach($metadata as $val) {
        if($val['key']===$key) {
            return $val;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Luego, hecho el json_decode del contenido que te viene:

```
$content = json_decode($the_woocommerce_content,true);
```

Obtenés el object con esa key de esta forma:

```
$_alg_wc_cog_cost = getMetadataByKey($content["meta_data"], "_alg_wc_cog_cost");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo tuve que hacer unos pocos cambios y !!LISTO!!...